# Thumbnail in twitter sometimes showing sometimes not

Tags: seo

When typing [www.8billionminds.com](http://www.8billionminds.com) or http://8billionminds.com on twitter, the image on the thumbnail shows correctly, but when typing https://8billionminds.com then it doesn't.

Any idea why?

It works fine on linkedin or facebook, but not twitter.

These are the meta tags

```html
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>8Billionminds | worldwide live learning platform</title>
  <meta
    name="description"
    content="We are a free online interactive learning platform where you can learn, teach and chat about almost anything."
  />
  <meta name="keywords" content="live learning, online learning" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="8Billionminds" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:location" content="en_UK" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.8billionminds.com/" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.8billionminds.com" />
  <meta
    property="og:title"
    content="8Billionminds | worldwide live learning platform"
  />
  <meta
    property="og:description"
    content="We are a free online interactive learning platform where you can learn, teach and chat about almost anything."
  />
  <meta property="og:image" content="${webAppRoot}images/8BM-open-graphic.png" />
  <meta property="og:image:alt" content="${webAppRoot}images/8BM-open-graphic.png" />
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@8Billionminds" />
  <meta
    name="twitter:title"
    content="8Billionminds | worldwide live learning platform"
  />
  <meta
    name="twitter:description"
    content="We are a free online interactive learning platform where you can learn, teach and chat about almost anything."
  />
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="${webAppRoot}images/8BM-open-graphic.png" />
  <meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="${webAppRoot}images/8BM-open-graphic.png" />
```

**EDIT**

It works fine now. I changed nothing.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

your  `og:url`

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.8billionminds.com/" />
```

has hardcoded `http` and `www`

EDIT:

checking on https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator
it seems to work

Comment: The validator seems to be working fine, but when twitting the thumbnail does not show correctly. Is that problem related with the hardcoded http and www? How would I fix it, and how come it works fine on linkedin and facebook?

Comment: Never mind. It works fine now. I changed nothing.

Comment: With issues like this, it's sometimes just a matter of patience. Something might be cached etc.